# Meaning of $ dx \times dy = k $

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Does $ dx \times dy = k $ have a mathematical meaning? What about when considering $y = y(x)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equation $\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y=k$ has a beautiful geometrical interpretation. We may interpret $\mathrm{d}x\text{ and }\mathrm{d}y$ as the sides of an infinitesimal rectangle on $\mathbb{R}^2$. Then, since $\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y=k$, we may take $k$ to be the area of the rectangle. If $y=y(x)$, then $\mathrm{d}\,x\mathrm{d}(y(x))$ has the exact same geometrical interpretation, except now, the height, i.e., $\mathrm{d}(y(x))$ depends on the base, i.e., $\mathrm{d}x$.